# Error al selccionar un item de una modal

Tags: javascript, html

Al querer seleccionar uno de los productos de la modal me aparece este error:

> ReferenceError: addproducto is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

La función `addproducto` ya se encuentra declarada en mi *js* aunque esté vacía, sigue arrojando el mismo error

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="tableresultproduct" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                            <table class="usuarios_table">  
                                <tr>
                                    <th><?php echo $text_img; ?></th>
                                    <th><?php echo $text_product; ?></th>
                                    <th><?php echo $text_code; ?></th>
                                    <th><?php echo $text_accion; ?></th>
                                </tr> 
                                
                                <?php foreach($productos as $cotizacion){?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="usuarios_table_td text_center"> <img src="<?php echo $cotizacion['img'];?>"> </td>
                                        <td class="usuarios_table_td text_center"> <?php echo $cotizacion['productoname'];?> </td>
                                        <td class="usuarios_table_td text_center"> <?php echo $cotizacion['productcode'];?> </td>
                                        <td class="usuarios_table_td text_center">
                                           <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="" onclick="addproducto('<?php echo $cotizacion['productcode'];?>');"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
                                        </td> 
                                    </tr>
                                <?php  } ?>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Saludos. Puede ser que nombre de `addproducto` no corresponda por mayúsculas/minúsculas en su declaración. o en su defecto su alcance; otra que lo tengas en un archivo JS que realmente no se esta cargando.

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar el código que usas para enlazar el archivo `.js` y también cómo defines la función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es recomendable utilizar **`onclick`** para hacer scripts apartados de una misma página, se recomienda mayormente utilizar **`addEventListener()`**.

Tampoco es buena recomendación ligar PHP y JavaScript en un mismo bloque, así que mi sugerencia para ti sería escribir el JavaScript y manejar las peticiones recurrentes con AJAX, que es lo recomendable.

Espero haberte ayudado, para más información puedes ver [esta pregunta:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick)